# Is there any way to avoid loading npm packages on pageload of React application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, slatejs

I am using few big sized npm packages (slate.js) in my project. The problem is, slate (and other npm packages) is automatically loaded on page load, even its only used inside a lazy-loaded component.

I am trying to avoid loading on pageload slate and few other packages.

So far, I used sideEffects and usedExports in my webpack configuration, but I couldnt accomplish anything useful. Webpack still automatically puts slate and other npm packages automatically in vendor.js as well as injecting it to published html file (by using HtmlWebpackPlugin I believe)

(fyi, I am using CRA along with config-overrides for webpack)

I don't think this code useful, but here is my webpack optimization property.

```
config.optimization = {
      usedExports: true,
      splitChunks: {
        chunks: "async",
        maxSize: 750000,
        cacheGroups: {
          react: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react|react-dom)[\\/]/,
            name: "react",
            chunks: "all",
          },
          slate: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](slate|slate-react)[\\/]/,
            name: "slate",
            chunks: "all",
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll also need to import the packages using [dynamic `import()`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Import):

```
// likely bundles slate up into your main vendor bundle :(
import slate from 'slate';
```

```
// slate will likely get its own webpack chunk, yay!
export default async function doSomethingWithSlate() {
  const slate = await import('slate');
  // do things with slate
}
```